# Spinner converter android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-adapterview

I am having some confusion with the spinner class in android. What I want to is make a converter, where the user picks a unit they want to convert, then in the second spinner pick the output unit. Ex Spinner 1: Yard² to Spinner 2: Feet². Im not sure how to set it up, so If yard² and feet² is selected then do this calculation. Here is the code I have so far:

```js
         private void UnitBegin_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)

        {
            Spinner UnitBegin = (Spinner)sender;
            string ubget = UnitBegin.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (ubget == "Yard²")
            {
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by declaring private globar Spinners, like this:

```
private Spinner spinner1;
private Spinner spinner2;

    // your code
    // now just use the globally declared spinners (spinner1 and spinner2) in your code
    private void UnitBegin_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selected1 = spinner1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string selected2 = spinner2.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if(selected1.Equals("Yard²"))
        {
            if (selected2.Equals("m²"))
            {
                //do calculation
            }
            else if (selected2.Equals("unit²"))
            {
                //do calculation
            }
            else if (selected2.Equals("otherunit²"))
            {
                //do calculation
            }
            else
            {
                //ERROR
            }
        }

        if (selected1.Equals("m²"))
        {
            if (selected2.Equals("Yard²"))
            {
                //do calculation
            }
            else if (selected2.Equals("unit²"))
            {
                //do calculation
            }
            else if (selected2.Equals("otherunit²"))
            {
                //do calculation
            }
            else
            {
                //ERROR
            }
        }
        //repeat for all the possible units

    }
```

But I would advise you to do something like this:

```
private Spinner spinner1;
private Spinner spinner2;
private float unit1;
private float unit2;

    // your code
    // now just use the globally declared spinners (spinner1 and spinner2) in your code
    private void UnitBegin_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selected1 = spinner1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if(selected1.Equals("Yard²"))
        {
            unit1 = 0.5 //let's say this is the multiplier from Yard² to m² :)
        }
        //repeat for all the possible units
    }

    private void UnitEnd_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selected2 = spinner2.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if(selected2.Equals("UNIT²"))
        {
            unit2 = 0.7 //let's say this is the multiplier from UNIT² to m² :)
        }
        //repeat for all the possible units
    }
```

And in the method that calculates the result to display:

```
float result = value*unit1; //and you get the value in the "default" unit
float finalResult = result*unit2; //and you get the value converted to the final unit

return finalResult; //return the final converted value
```